# How to tell that an extension method returns non-null if subject is not null

Tags: kotlin, type-inference

I have implemented the following method:

```
private fun String?.replaceHolder(item: String): String? {
  return this?.replace("\$deployUnit", item)
}
```

The code that is using it looks like that:

```
val a = "aaa".replaceHolder("fff")
```

However, the inferred type of a is `String?`.
With contracts I can say that if the return value is not null then subject was is not null like that:

```
@ExperimentalContracts
private fun String?.replaceHolder(item: String): String? {
  contract {
    returnsNotNull() implies (this@replaceHolder != null)
  }
  return this?.replace("\$deployUnit", item)
}
```

Is it possible to say the opposite? I mean to infer that the type of `a` is not null? Is there another way to do that?

Comment: My own preference would probably be to define it on `String` and use `?.` explicitly when needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if i understand you well this is what you want

```
private fun <T: String?> T.replaceHolder(item: String): T {
    return this?.replace("\$deployUnit", item) as T
}
```

T extends String? means that T type can be String or null or both and every type T is, function return that type too

Comment: Thanks! other than the unchecked cast that is what I wanted so it's great.